# Sending adaptive card to multiple users in Teams referencing Forms dynamic content

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards, ms-forms

Based on the value of a question submitted in a Microsoft Form, I want to send an adaptive card to one or more people via Teams. I think I have the end steps figured out. I have the adaptive card nested within an Apply to each action. The Recipient of the adaptive card is set to the Current item of the Apply to each, and the selection on the Apply to each is the output from a variable.

That variable is where I'm hung up. I'm currently using an if formula to calculate the email addresses. This is probably where I need help.

```
if(equals(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r43d6bce2bb684bf79bff6d8c61fb8f9c'],'Finance'),'josh@.com',if(equals(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r43d6bce2bb684bf79bff6d8c61fb8f9c'],'Sales Operations'),'robby@.com','josh@.com'))
```

Comment: Are you using the bot? You can send adaptive cards to team/group/1:1 by getting user id / channel id. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#get-the-user-id-or-teamchannel-id)?

Answer (score 0):

You can send adaptive cards to team/group/1:1 by getting user id / channel id.please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#get-the-user-id-or-teamchannel-id)

Comment: I want to send a single adaptive card to multiple user IDs. Not to a channel or a team.

Comment: Yes, you can send to multiple user's using user id. You can user id using [List uers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API or you need to store theuser id when user install the app and use the for further use. Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#get-the-user-id-or-teamchannel-id)